Firestore doesn't work in Zoom App Mobile Client
I have this page for Zoom App's Home URL. I want to capture Meeting's UID and send the person to another page depending on their role - participant vs host.
It was perfectly fine on laptop Zoom client. However, I get the error on iOS Zoom client "FirebaseError: Failed to get document because the client is offline."
Any idea why? Why would Firebase not connect on ios but connect on laptop Zoom client?
Thanks!
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import zoomSdk from "@zoom/appssdk";
import app from "@/lib/firebase";
import {
  getFirestore,
  doc,
  setDoc,
  getDoc,
  serverTimestamp,
} from "firebase/firestore";

export default function ZoomPage() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const db = getFirestore(app);
  const [feedbackList, setFeedbackList] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    async function initializeZoomApp() {
      try {
        await zoomSdk.config({
          popoutSize: { width: 480, height: 360 },
          capabilities: ["shareApp"],
        });

        const userContext = await zoomSdk.getUserContext();
        let { meetingUUID } = await zoomSdk.getMeetingUUID();
        meetingUUID = meetingUUID.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "");

        const sessionRef = doc(db, "sessions", meetingUUID);
        const docSnapshot = await getDoc(sessionRef);
        if (!docSnapshot.exists()) {
          await setDoc(sessionRef, {
            createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
            createdBy: "Zoom",
          });
        }

        if (userContext.role !== "attendee") {
          window.location.href = `/start?id=${meetingUUID}&zoom=true`;
        } else {
          window.location.href = `/join?id=${meetingUUID}&zoom=true`;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error initializing Zoom App:", error);
        setFeedbackList(error)
      }
    }

    initializeZoomApp();
  }, [router]);

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
        <title>Zoom App</title>
      </Head>
      <p>{feedbackList}</p>
    </>
  );
}


